# Simple way to always make a field lowercase in db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Currently I'm doing the following in the model:

```
before_save :to_lower
before_create :to_lower

def to_lower
  self.name = self.name.downcase
end
```

Seems pretty repetitive to me.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You don't need the before_create if you already have before_save.

```
before_save { |user| user.name = user.name.downcase }
```

Comment: How about before_save { user.name.downcase! } ?

Comment: @AmitPandya I ended up doing before_save { |user| user.name.downcase! }
Which works quite well, i think you still have to use |user| or you having nothing to reference.

Comment: @BaneOfSerenity, Which rails version are you using?

Comment: be careful if `name` is optional, it's better to use try.

Answer (score 3):

I generally handle such cases by:

```
def name= name
  super(name.try(:downcase))
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def name=(val)
  write_attribute(:name, val.downcase)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing this? If it's to perform case-insensitive searches, you might just want to put that into your query logic (actually, I think Rails does a bit of that already). However, if you actually want the data normalized to lowercase in the DB (say, if you're dealing with SHA1 hashes or something), then you're doing the right thing.

Comment: You could do this in the DB but it'd be terribly inefficient.

Comment: @Tom: Why do you say that? For certain use cases (e.g. the normalization case I mentioned), doing it in the DB would be far more efficient.

Comment: @Marmen Sorry for the confusion, I'm mainly referring to the part of doing case-insensitive searches in the query logic. `WHERE LOWER(field) = LOWER(input)` is substantially slower than `WHERE field = LOWER(input)`.

Comment: @MarnenLaibow-Koser LOWER() apply a function on each field, this is terribly inneficient because it avoid using indexes.

Comment: @ArnoldRoa You can actually index on lower(field) if you want to.