# Rails downcase params for an inclusion validation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, activerecord, devise

So I have a validation for an invite code in a Rails 4 App with Devise. To create an account with devise the user has to enter a validation code. It looks like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :invite_code, inclusion: {
    in: %w(foo347 bar362 foobarr100),
    message: "Rails 4 app is invite only at this time, please sign up for a code."
  }
```

It works great but I want to make it case insensitive so fOo347 or BaR362 will work . I tried doing a before_save  like so:

```
  before_save { |user| user.name = user.name.downcase }
```

per the instructions here
[Simple way to always make a field lowercase in db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8096673/simple-way-to-always-make-a-field-lowercase-in-db)  .

It's not working though, I think because it's a validation. I also tried swapping the `before_save` for a `before_create` with no luck. How can I downcase the field before it hits the validation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `before_validation` callback instead:

```
before_validation { self.user.name = self.user.name.downcase }
```

Comment: Be careful, ''.downcase! returns nil, this may be unexpected!

Comment: @HieuPham you are absolutely right! Thanks for pointing that out, I have edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about you downcase the params at the controller?

or you can use before [validation callback](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html#module-ActiveRecord::Callbacks-label-before_validation-2A+returning+statements) like taglia proposed

Comment: I would have done it in the controller but due to the fact that I am using Devise there is no create action in the controller. The validation callback worked!

Comment: What do you there is no create action in devise controller? You can overwrite [Devise controller](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-controllers) if you want to